# J48 Classification using Weka

Tags: weka

I have some data to classify, however I can't post here so I made a similar (yet silly) example of the data, (similar attributes and data), my arff contents:

```
@Relation Food

@Attribute  Type { Healthy ,  Not_Healthy}
@Attribute Veggie   {TRUE, FALSE}
@Attribute From { McDonalds ,  BurgerKing ,  Hardees ,  Somewhere  ,  SomewhereElse }
@Attribute Size    {Small ,  Large}
@Attribute WithBun {'y', 'n'}
@Attribute meat {'y', 'n'}
@Attribute Sauce {'y', 'n'}
@Attribute Syrup {'y', 'n'}
@Attribute Cheese {'y', 'n'}
@Attribute Mayo {'y', 'n'}
@Attribute Ketchup {'y', 'n'}
@Attribute Sweetner {'y', 'n'}
@Attribute Milk {'y', 'n'}
@Attribute Food_is    { Burger,  Ribs ,  Nuggets,  Donuts , Hotdog,  Pizza ,  Rice_Pudding , Steak , Fries, Fatty_food }


@data
 Healthy ,TRUE,  BurgerKing , Large, 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n' , Burger 
 Not_Healthy ,TRUE, McDonalds , Small , 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'y', 'n' ,  Ribs 
 Healthy ,TRUE, McDonalds , Large, 'y','y', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n' , Donuts
 Not_Healthy ,FALSE, Hardees , Large , 'y','y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', Hotdog
 Not_Healthy ,TRUE, Somewhere , Small ,'y','y', 'y','y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'n','n',Pizza
 Healthy ,TRUE, SomewhereElse , Large , 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n',Pizza
 Not_Healthy ,TRUE, McDonalds , Small , 'n','n','y','y','n','y','n','n','n', Donuts
 Not_Healthy ,FALSE, Hardees , Large , 'n', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n',Fries
 Not_Healthy ,FALSE, Hardees , Large ,'n','y', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'y', Rice_Pudding
 Not_Healthy ,FALSE, Hardees , Large, 'n', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', Steak
```

Result of classification is: 5 out of 10 classified correctly, and tree looks like this:
[image: J48 Tree]

- Class assigned to last attribute, why tree doesn't really reflect data? what am I doing wrong here?

By reflection I don't mean (veggie should be this or that) I mean the tree should be deeper and should contain more levels.

Thanks

Comment: Any chance you can upload data somewhere and share  link for us to check?

Comment: Copy the above quoted data and save it to text file then rename it as .arff

Comment: This is probably due to the options with which you train the classifier. can you add them to you post?